# Changing the volume of a QTMovie playing an mp3

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using a QTMovie to play audio tracks. I've just started playing around with the volume controls and I'm changing the volume using setVolume:(float)newVolume. The problem I'm having is that the volume change seems very very miniscule. I have tried varying the volume between 0 and 10 and 0 and 128 (the maximum) and the difference in loudness is very hard to detect.

Is there anyone with any experience of this that could point out something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a QTMovie to play audio tracks. I've just started playing around with the volume controls and I'm changing the volume using setVolume:(float)newVolume. The problem I'm having is that the volume change seems very very miniscule. I have tried varying the volume between 0 and 10 and 0 and 128 (the maximum) and the difference in loudness is very hard to detect.

The difference is hard to detect because there isn't one.

`setVolume:` takes a floating-point fraction, and you're treating it as an integer. The range is from 0.0 to 1.0, as documented in [the documentation for the `volume` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovie/volume):

> #### `volume`
>
> Returns the movie’s volume as a scalar value of type `float`.
>
> ```
> - (float)volume
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> The valid range is 0.0 to 1.0.

The documentation doesn't specify what happens when you try to set an out-of-range value; my guess is that it currently clamps to 1.0, so all values greater than or equal to 1.0 end up as 1.0, for exactly no difference in loudness.

Comment: Ah, I completely glazed over that sentence in the documentation. Thank you! Dunno why it lets you set the volume up to 128 though.